# How to access a function in a Webpack bundle from a HTML script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

The problem is that I would like to make a timeout function on my page.
I have a silverlight app and a new react app in the page. 
This 2 "apps" need to have a common timer variable that I can in React read and display a `<Div>` if time is more then 10min.

The SilverLight app can call a JS function on every click. This works, but I'm not able to call a function inside the webpack bundled file?? 
Is it not possible to reach functions from a js function in a `<script>` from html side??

Do I have to send the Silverlight click time to the server and then do a ajax call from React every 1min or so to see if the Silverlight has been active? (does not sound like a good approach)
Hope you can point me in the right direction or show me a good way to solve this problem for me :) and remember I'm new to react and webpack so I'm not able to use the right google words to find the solution myself.

Answer (score 10):

This is a very common question. There are different ways you could do this.

**Method 1**

If there are multiple such functions you would like to use outside of it, then you have to export the function using:

```
module.exports = {
      yourfunctionName
}
```

And then you have to configure your webpack to treat this as a library. This is how most of the libraries do. Now to access the function outside the bundled file. Simply use your library name (*as configured in webpack*) for e.g, let's say my library name is myLibrary then the code will be:

```
myLibrary.yourFunctionName
```

**Method 2**

if you don't need to export many functions or you are looking for a quick easy answer to this then you can add your functions to window object, which makes it available everywhere.

In your main file (which is going to be bundled) **filename.bundle.js**

```
window.functionName = yourFunction;
```

And wherever you want to access that function outside of bundle

```
window.functionName();
```

It isn't advisable to put the functions in window object, But if you are looking for quick easy fix then method 2 is good for you.

Comment: Good answer but it would be nice if you could explain how to "configure your webpack to treat this as a library."

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is a bit of a tricky question because Webpack bundles are usually self-contained and it's impossible to load modules and access their exports outside of the Webpack runtime the compilation is bound to. This was for a bit of background.

What you're looking for is the [`expose-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader). It will allow you to expose exports of a module to the global scope.

```
// Exposes the exports for file.js to the global context
// on property "libraryName".
//
// In web browsers, window.libraryName is then available.
require('expose-loader?libraryName!./file.js');
```