# Exporting and bundling a function using webpack and calling it inside html script tag

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have been trying something very simple - export and bundle (and babel transpiling) a function using webpack  and then call it in my html page's script tag.

sample.js - which is bundled using webpack

```
export default function sampleFunctionExported1(){
    console.log("sampleFunctionExported1");
}
```

Webpack config (version = 4.44.1)

```
module.exports = (env, arguments) => {
    entry: {
            main: ['./assets/js/sample.js', './assets/css/main.scss'],
            entry2: ['./assets/js/entry2.js', './assets/css/entry2.scss']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../public/js'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: 'MyLibrary',
        libraryTarget: 'var',

        // some additional configs/options that I have tried          
        // libraryTarget: 'window', // tried with this option, it does not work
        // libraryTarget: 'umd',  // tried with this option, it does not work
        // libraryExport: 'default', // tried with this option, it does not work
    }
```

I though it was as easy as adding the `library` and `libraryTarget` targets to webpack config and then I should be able to call my function as `MyLibrary.sampleFunctionExported1()`.

But when I do `MyLibrary` in my browser console, it displays as below and `MyLibrary.sampleFunctionExported1()` return `... is not a function` error

[image: MyLibrary]

I have followed suggestions in many of these questions/answers: [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285725/unable-to-access-function-bundled-by-webpack), [answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298736/how-to-access-a-function-in-a-webpack-bundle-from-a-html-script) and various other blog posts but it does not work for me at all.

So after spending so much time, I am posting it here hoping that someone can help me understand what is wrong.

**Edit 1:**
Here is ithe file generated after webpack bundling: [/public/js/sample.js](https://gist.github.com/aarangara/8e03756c4d43b4a9cc4e28976007e00b)

P.S. - Ignore the `entry2.js` file as it's an empty file, I just added it to show my config and because I am not sure if having multiple entry points can cause this issue which I am facing currently.

Comment: Is `MyLibrary.default` present? I'd think `MyLibrary.sampleFunctionExported1` would only be there if you did it as a named export instead of a default export.

Comment: can you share your transpiled `../public/js/sample.js` here or as a gist? might help the diagnosis. 

FWIW, in the past, I often target umd, and they ... seem to work ... after some tweaking.

Comment: @Jacob - Actually I noticed that MyLibrary is not an empty object and it has `default` present in it but my function call still returns undefined error (I have updated my question with MyLibrary object pic)

Comment: @pandamakes - added the generated/bundled file

Comment: pasted the code in browser, and it seem `MyLibrary.default()` calls the function you wanted. 

which... makes sense, since it's the default export...

Comment: perhaps remove the default keyword if you want to use named function? , ie `MyLibrary.sampleFunctionExported1()`

Answer (score 1):

Because of how you're exporting:

```
export default function sampleFunctionExported1(){
    console.log("sampleFunctionExported1");
}
```

...your `MyLibrary` variable is going to have the shape:

```
{
  default: function() { ... }
}
```

If you instead want it to have the shape:

```
{
  sampleFunctionExported1: function() { ... }
}
```

...you need to do a named export instead of a default export:

```
export function sampleFunctionExported1() {
  console.log("sampleFunctionExported1");
}
```